# Mupen64plus Library not found

Tags: mint

I have downloaded mupen64plus,m64py and installed them both but my problem is that the library cannot be found. I then went onto https://github.com/mupen64plus/mupen64plus-core/releases and downloaded the bundle for the linux 32 bit. It is now in my download folder. How do i add this to m64py?

Answer (score 0):

I would install it with `sudo apt-get install mupen64plus`.

The problem is you downloaded them, but the M64Py is not findig the Mupen64Plus' shared libraries, because you may not install these to the right directory. Probably the above command install the libraries to the right place.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the default locations if that helps. I accidentally deleted one of the lines and it took me half an hour to find the defaults again (purging all the pieces and re-installing them did not help)[Here is a screenshot of the default settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EzUP2.png)